# Can I use a database built in SharePoint for data validation in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint-online

I have a dataset that is being built in SharePoint that contains data including job codes, dates, descriptions, and other variables. I want to limit data entry in an Excel spreadsheet to only values in the SharePoint dataset. Possible? Well I know it's possible.. but HOW?!

Comment: Where does Access fit into this?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the SharePoint list into Excel. Click the **Export to Excel** command in the SharePoint list.

[image]

That will download or open a query file. If it only downloads, double click to open the file with Excel. Enable data connections when prompted.

[image]

Confirm that the data should be loaded into a new workbook, or, if you already have a prepared file open, use that and load the data into a new worksheet.

[image]

When you do that, a dynamic data connection is created. This data connection can be configured to refresh each time the workbook is opened. **Data Ribbon > Queries & Connections > Right click the query in the query panel > Properties**

[image]

You can then use the query data for the data validation.